# Subclassing QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt, events, subclass, qpixmap

I would like to get mouse press events on a QPixmap in Qt.
I tried to subclass it using:

```
class CustomPixmap : public QPixmap
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CustomPixmap(QPaintDevice *parent = NULL);
    ~CustomPixmap() {};

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

};
```

But it does not compile because of the error

```
./moc_output/moc_customPixmap.cpp:52:8: error: no member named
      'staticMetaObject' in 'QPixmap'; did you mean simply 'staticMetaObject'?
```

Taking the Q_OBJECT out compiles fine, but the mousePressEvent is not called. How can I properly subclass a QPixmap to get mouse press events ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up in using a QPushButton:

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
button->setIcon(QIcon(myQPixmap));
buttonWidget=MySceneClass->scene()->addWidget(button);
QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(clickedSlot()));
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense to receive mouse events on a QPixmap, because a QPixmap is not a QWidget and therefore the QPixmap is never directly present in your Qt GUI.

What *is* on screen is a QWidget of some sort that draws and displays the QPixmap.  This might be a QLabel or perhaps a QWidget whose paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) method has been overridden to call painter.drawPixmap() with your QPixmap as an argument.  The sensible place to override mousePressEvent() would be in a subclass of that widget, not by subclassing QPixmap.

Comment: Thanks; So concretely how to link my QPixmap to a QWidget ?

Comment: Adding the Pixmap to my QGraphicsScene gives me a QGraphicsPixmapItem. Is this the one on which I should intercept the mouse events ? If yes how,  thanks.

Comment: Override the QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMousePressEvent *) method.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mousePressEvent